# Double-slit experiment and uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, double-slit-experiment

In single-slit experiment for electrons, it is possible to infer the uncertainty principle (ΔΔp~h)
if interference pattern is interpreted as range of possible momentum of electron. As the slit's width (Δ) increases, the width of the momentum distribution (Δp) decreases and vice versa. If uncertainty principle is an intrinsic property in quantum systems so how to infer this principle in double-slit experiment? I know when we put detectors at slits (to measure position) the electron behave like a particle at slits and the probabilistic wave collapses and the interference pattern disappears. As far as I can understand is that this may be interpreted as complementarity but this does not show the uncertainty relation explicitly (ΔΔp~h).[image: uncertainty principle in single-slit experiment].